# How can std::set::erase(const key_type& key) cause segfault?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, segmentation-fault, set

I'm tracking a bug and I run into very strange behaviour. I have set of pointers and when I erase them one-by-one, first one erases, but erasing another gives me segfault.
I use

```
   size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

so it can't be something with iterators. My debuger shows me that in callstack:

```
0 - std::less<cSubscriber *>::operator() //cSubscriber is an abstract base class and I have a set of cSubscriber *

1 - std::_Rb_tree<cSubscriber*, cSubscriber*, std::_Identity<cSubscriber*>, std::less<cSubscriber*>, std::allocator<cSubscriber*> >::equal_range

2 -  std::_Rb_tree<cSubscriber*, cSubscriber*, std::_Identity<cSubscriber*>, std::less<cSubscriber*>, std::allocator<cSubscriber*> >::erase

3 - std::set<cSubscriber*, std::less<cSubscriber*>, std::allocator<cSubscriber*> >::erase

4 - cEventSystem::unsubscribe //my function, it is as follows in the class which has the set as its member

cEventSystem::unsubscribe(cSubscriber * ptr)
{
   set.erase(ptr);
}
```

And in the base cSubscriber abstract class there is virtual destructor:

```
  virtual ~cSubscriber()
  {
      eventSystem.unsubscribe(this);
  }
```

Any ideas? I have no idea how can it cause segfault, the erase should just return 0 when there isn't such an element. Or maybe it crashesh when trying to erase something from empty container? (I have another bug when after adding 3 differents pointers the size of set is only 2 but that's another story).

Comment: what's the exact declaration of your used `std::set<>`? any special compare-function?

Comment: @akira from the backstack 3 we can see that it is the default one.

Comment: @akira everything default.

Comment: Any chance of you having multiple threads accessing your set?

Comment: @ André Puel single thread application

Comment: @user1873947 Wait... What is an cSubscriber::eventSystem? A reference? A pointer? A static variable?

Comment: @André Puel reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a invalid address to your `std::set<SOMETHING*>::erase()` it will segfault when trying to compare the passed value with what is in the container.

For example:

```
struct IntPtrComparer {
    bool operator()(int* a, int* b) const {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};

std::set<int*,IntPtrComparer> a;
a.insert(new int);
a.erase(NULL);
```

## Update

<sup>based on comments</sup>

Since you are not redefining the default comparator, and the default comparator does not dereference your pointers, then the only way is that your `std::set` is corrupted.

Internally, `std::set` is implemented as a binary tree. This mean that it has a lot of pointers in the way to find a value and to erase it. If `std::set` is corrupted some of theses pointers will point to a invalid memory address. This invalid memory address will be used to pass a **reference** (reference of a pointer, `cSubscriber* & const`) of the compared value to `std::less`. `std::less` receives a reference to a pointer and is going to dereference the reference to get the pointer value.

This way, a invalid memory inside the `std::set` did only show up at `std::less`, because the `std::set` did not actually touch the invalid memory, it gave the invalid memory address to our poor fella `std::less` that opened it and got a *segfault* in it's face.

My point with all that is that if you create a comparator that uses copies instead of reference, the corruption will show up inside the `std::set` when it tries to copy the pointer value to give to the comparator.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't it say "okay, i have no NULL value in the set, so I will errase nothing"?

Comment: @akira Yeah, I saw that after I answered the question. Improved the code to show the point.

Comment: But, it only applies to deference and why the hell the set would want to dereference the pointer given to erase()?

Comment: @user1873947 Didnt you redefine `std::less<cSubscriber*>`?

Comment: user1873947: coz it uses IntPtrComparer to calculate the `value` to the given key ... and that `value` must be unique, not the `key`.

Comment: but he's using std::less which doesn't deref

Comment: I didn't touch std::less or anything. I didn't overload any operator too.

Comment: what is probably happening is that your *this* is screwed up. i.e. you called *unsubscribe* on a dangling pointer.

Comment: @thang is it possible because of the order which virtual destructor from base class and the normal destructor are called?

Comment: Well, your question was "How can std::erase segfault", I showed how. The specific problem in your specific code is impossible to figure out with the little information you have given.

Comment: @André Puel I see, so I know one of the options but it's not the problem in my code.

Comment: @thang it crashes when I call erase(0x8b9bd8) which seems to be valid adress AFAIK. it's not null.

Comment: @user1873947 I am sorry, but I am pretty sure the stdc++ lib is correct and your code is wrong. Not offense intended, please =)

Comment: @akira I didn't touch any of the comparision functions or operators.

Comment: @André Puel well there are a lot of bugs in g++ stdlib implementation, but I know that for 99% it's something wrong in my code, but well, how can calling set.erase( (cSubscriber *)0x8b9bd8 ) cause segfault. The only idea is that it is dereferenced, but it shouldn't as I didn't touch anything.

Comment: why don't you print the *this* before erase is called.

Comment: @thang I print it. As I said it's 0x8b9bd8 which seems quite valid as long it doesn't get dereferenced.

Comment: change cEventSystem::unsubscribe(cSubscriber * ptr)
{
   set.erase(ptr);
} to cEventSystem::unsubscribe(cSubscriber * ptr)
{  printf("%08x", this); // replace with cout if you're picky
   set.erase(ptr);
}

Comment: @thang for the first erase (which works okay) the this is 5a5eb5d0. The interesting thing is that in second (segfaulting) call of unsubscribe, the "print this" line (which is before erase) is just nothing.

Comment: what is nothing? try  printf("[%08x]\n", this); probably a dangling pointer issue... need to trace up above the destructor

Comment: @thang it means that the line doesn't get called at all. I thing I got it, but no idea how to fix it - when closing the app, the destructor order is that eventsystem object (which keeps the set) is destroyed before all subscribers get destroyed and the ~cSubscriber() wants to access eventsystem object, which doesn't exist. I may be wrong though, but it seems possible.

Comment: @user1873947 Your cSubscriber and your eventSystem are all static allocated variables? If so, it is your problem.

Comment: @André Puel they are global objects inside main() function. So you say it's the destructing order?

Comment: Put a printf on eventSystem destructor and one on cSubscriber destructor. It will show you.

Comment: @André Puel I did it and the event system destructor isn't called before the segfault, so that's not the problem....

Comment: I think tommorow I will put the code on the pastebin and make new question with it because the full code is required to track the issue.